# origin of the "missing dollar puzzle"

Tags: puzzle-history

I am wondering when [the missing dollar puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2297/70) first appeared. I am sure I read it forty years ago or so, but maybe it is much older. Does anyone knows it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has been dated back as far as 1933, published in a book, *Diversion and Pastimes* by R.M. Abraham.

Source: http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-workout/200912/where-is-the-missing-dollar